# How do I compile a C++ program I made in vim?

Tags: compiling, c++

Whenever I type in `g++ toe.ccp` this comes up:

```
/usr/bin/ld:toe.ccp: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:toe.ccp:1: syntax error
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears you have the wrong file extension. You created a file which you called `toe.ccp`, however what you want is a file that is `toe.cpp` (Two p's, not two c's in your file extension). Renaming the file will cause g++ to work correctly.

In case you are unfamiliar with how to do so on the command line, you can do

```bsh
mv toe.ccp toe.cpp
```

in the terminal to rename the file. Then try compiling it with g++, it should now work.

Comment: Another option (in case the poster really needs the suffix to be `.ccp` for some reason) is to declare the source language explicitly using the `-x` option e.g. `g++ -x c++ toe.ccp`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the correct file extension for the program. `toe.ccp` is not recognized by GCC as a source file format because of the file extension, so it doesn't know what to do with it. You probably meant to save your file as `toe.cpp` instead.

As shown in the GCC user manual section on [input file names](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html), there are a predefined list of file extensions for each recognized programming language. C++ source files can end in `.cc`, `.cp`, `.cxx`, `.cpp`, `.CPP`, `.c++`, or `.C`.